# Postgres: How to transform data in two cursors before comparison?

Tags: postgresql, pgtap

I am replacing a legacy function `get_data` in our database which takes some `entity_id` and returns a refcursor.

I am writing a new function `get_data_new` which is using different data sources, but the outputs are expected to be the same as `get_data` for the same input.

I'd like to verify this with pgtap, and am doing so as follows within a test (with `_expected` and `_actual` being the names of the returned cursors):

```
SELECT schema.get_data('_expected', 123);
SELECT schema.get_data_new('_actual', 123);

SELECT results_eq(
    'FETCH ALL FROM _actual',
    'FETCH ALL FROM _expected',
    'get_data_new should return identical results to the legacy version'
);
```

This works as expected for other functions, but the query in `get_data` happens to return some `json` columns meaning that comparison expectedly fails with `ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json`.

I'd rather leave the legacy function untouched so refactoring to `jsonb` isn't possible. I'm imagining a workaround to be transforming the data before comparison, hypothetically with something like `SELECT entity_id, json_column::jsonb FROM (FETCH ALL FROM _actual)`, but this specific attempt obviously isn't valid.

What would be a suggested approach here? Write a helper function to insert data from the cursors into a couple of temporary tables? I'm hoping there's a cleaner solution I haven't discovered.

Using postgres 11.14, pgtap11

Comment: Write a wrapper function for the old version?

Comment: Thanks @RichardHuxton. Have [written a wrapper function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70870786/6772415) for the cursors to allow SELECTing from them so we can do arbitrary transformations of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Have solved it by creating a function to loop over the cursor and return the results as a table. Unfortunately this isn't a generic solution - it only works for the cursors with specific data.

In this specific case, `json_column` can be implicitly converted to type `jsonb` so this is all that is needed. However, we can now `SELECT * FROM cursor_to_table('_actual')` meaning we can do whatever transformations we require on the result.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cursor_to_table(_cursor refcursor)
RETURNS TABLE (entity_id bigint, json_column jsonb)
AS $func$
BEGIN
    LOOP
        FETCH _cursor INTO entity_id, json_column
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

        RETURN NEXT;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT results_eq(
    'SELECT * FROM cursor_to_table(''_actual'')',
    'SELECT * FROM cursor_to_table(''_expected'')',
    'get_data_new should return identical results to the legacy version'
);
```